# ActiveRecord associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, associations

I have a database compose of Scenes and Characters

A character belongs_to zero or many scenes and a scene can have zero or many characters.

**Scene model**

```
class Scene < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :chapter
    has_many :characters
end
```

**Scene database**

```
class CreateScenes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :scenes do |t|
      t.text :narrative
      t.string :place
      t.string :period
      t.integer :chapter_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Character model**

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :scene
end
```

**Character database**

```
class CreateCharacters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :characters do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :role
      t.integer :scene_id

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

When I delete a scene, I want to update the character and turn to blank the column scene_id.
I used dependent: :destroy, but it does not do what I'm looking for.

I hope you understant what I want, and sorry for my bad english
Thanks

Comment: You say "A character belongs_to zero or many scenes " - do you mean "zero or one scenes"?  If you want it to be zero-to-many you'll need to set up a join table so that each side can has_many of the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `dependent: :nullify` which will set the column to nil.  I think that's what you're looking for

Comment: Great, thank you for your answer. I wish I will found documentation on "dependent"

Comment: @Asm You can find more on dependent [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#dependent) in rails guides